# Potentiometer/trimpot range 503 vs 103 with a resistor in series

Tags: potentiometer, trimpots

**Small intro:**
I'm adapting this NE555+CD4017 module to fit into a nice little box and I am switching out the plastic trimpot that came with the package for a metal one that can fit through wood.
The trouble is, only now I see that the trimpot that came with the module, was a 103 (plastic) instead of the 503 it should have been - as indicated on the diagram and pictures of the module.
I ordered a replacement 10k metal potentiometer because I based myself off the '103' indication on the actual module instead of the diagram... silly me.
It's only now that I notice the 10-50k difference because I was looking up how to wire them up again.

- picture of diagram & components in question

[image]

**Actual question:**
Right now the LEDs get shifted really fast (because of the 103- 10k pot?) and I think it should be able to go a lot slower if I use the 503 - 50k pot).
If I put in some extra resistors, say 20k worth more in series with the 10k potentiometer, would the shifting of the LED lights go slower by default?
And if I just order a new metal 50k potentiometer I would probably have the whole range (slow-fast)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you not able to determine if the leds shift slower when the resistance of R4 is increased?

Comment: @jsotola my stock of extra components is "0"
So if I were to test with different stuff, I would have to go buy some - that's why it is theory only right now :|

Comment: Get a resistor kit, or a grab-bag.  A good resistor kit will be more expensive, but will have better coverage and quality.  A grab-bag (if you can even still get them) will be factory floor-sweepings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You could also increase the value of C1.